# How to get a Canadian visa after having been deported from USA fifteen years ago?

Tags: visas, canada

I was deported 15 years ago from USA, because I was living and working as an illegal alien.  Last year I applied for a student visa to Canada and it was denied because my travel history.  Is there any chance for me to obtain a visa to Canada someday?

Comment: Yes there is a chance, however it is very very very slim because USA and Canada are like twins. You apply just like anyone else and answer truthfully and hope

Comment: What did it say in the refusal letter? 15 years is a really long time and I don't think the deportation is the only reason for the refusal. How old are you? Wanting to study 15 years after being deported for working illegally doesnt really seem credible.

Comment: @greatone I started my PhD studies 32 years after starting my first job. 15 years is not that long.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.